# Flutter - XCode Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Mac M1

Tags: xcode, flutter

I see this issue has been raised, but I haven't managed to solve it.

I got new Mac Mini M1 chip.

I am getting this problem when running the flutter app on ios simulator. Android works fine.
Happens with new and old projects alike.

**Failed to package /Users/reuvenberman/StudioProjects/yet_again.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale
en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this worked, but it did.
I switched to Flutter master channel, then it worked. Then I switched back to stable channel, and it still works.
This took me 3 days, and still don't understand.

Comment: Facing same issue ! Tries your solution but sill no luck !

Comment: It worked for me. I am setting up my new mac today, and find that even a new flutter project can not be built for iOS. I tried many solutions but none of them worked. When I switch to the master channel, everything gets OK. Thanks for saving my day